# Scrambler puzzle (CTF forensics problem by me!)

Tags: visual, steganography

Before anyone starts hyperventilating, *this is not part of an ongoing CTF*! I just made this example CTF problem for fun...

To learn more about what a CTF is, check out [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capture_the_flag#Computer_security).

---

For this problem, the flag is in the format: (so you'll know when you've found it)

`flag{xxxxxxx}`

---

Here is what you have to work with: (Google Drive links; you should open these in new tabs)

- [flag.png](https://drive.google.com/file/d/141SyRPVYNdqv0Cz92oPX8fqx_2i0NGw7/view?usp=sharing)
- [key.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N4qXUbN4-ZrXbFD7FwSuC8R0t7D0rj1L/view?usp=sharing)

---

#### <strike>If the bounty ends without someone getting the flag, I'll post my own writeup.</strike>

#### [My writeup](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/99067/58672) has been posted!

---

#### Hint 0

> Have you read the title of the question? "Scrambler puzzle..." Hmmmm... So are we scrambling something? Or perhaps something was scrambled?

#### Hint 1

> [image: lightbulb flashing on and off]

#### Hint 2

> [image: binary joke tshirt]

#### Hint 3

> Unscramble the image using the key, then apply hints 1 and 2 to the result to get the flag.

Comment: Are you sure that the key is correct? I have tried unscrambling the flag more than 50 times iteratively with the key file. It didn't work. So, tried enciphering the image (scrambling the image) nearly the same amount of time and it didn't work too.

Comment: Did you use AES in counter mode to encipher (scramble) the image?

Comment: Rot13(Bar boivbhf guvat vf gung lbh unir hfrq zbqhyb-37 nevguzrgvp va pbyhzaf 0 naq 2 naq zbqhyb-8 nevguzrgvp va pbyhzaf 1 naq 3 va) key.txt

Comment: @JohnBrookfields — For your first comment: it’s a little bit more than just that. For your second and third comments: it’s not quite as complicated as that.

Comment: @JohnBrookfields -- Perhaps Hint 1 will be helpful!

Comment: Qb lbh zrna gung gur xrl svyr zhfg ybbx yvxr [guvf](https://pastebin.com/iQ8Bvifq), fubhyq or cnqqrq jvgu 0 gb n yratgu bs 8 be fbzrguvat ryfr?

Comment: @JohnBrookfields -- Unfortunately, I cannot answer any more questions. But have you looked at the new hint? It might help you with your result after your process from the very first comment.

Comment: Yeah, that was what my previous comment was about. Did you have a look at the link? @VoldemortsWrath

Comment: @JohnBrookfields — I did have a look at it but I cannot tell you anything unfortunately. :):)

Comment: The T-shirt hint means binary number system? (10)base 2 = (2)base 10

Comment: @AlwaysConfused -- Yes, that was my intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## My Own Writeup

From the title and Hint 0, we can guess that `flag.png` was scrambled in some way. Looking at `key.txt`, we can assume that it is formatted like this:

> OLD_X OLD_Y NEW_X NEW_Y
>   OLD_X OLD_Y NEW_X NEW_Y
>   OLD_X OLD_Y NEW_X NEW_Y

So, writing a Python program (using [PIL](https://pypi.org/project/PIL/)), we can unscramble `flag.png` to get the image with all of its `OLD_X`s and `OLD_Y`s. The unscrambled image looks something like this:

[image: unscrambled image]
<sub><sup>(enlarged to show detail)</sup></sub>

Now, using Hints 1 and 2, we see that this image is encoded with something that has to do with binary. It’s also very interesting that there are 8 rows (meaning the number of pixels is a multiple of 8). This suggests that the actual pixels represent some binary value. What we can do with this is assume that the dark pixels represent 0’s and the light ones represent 1’s. Here’s what this might look like:

[image: binary numbers]
<sub><sup>(enlarged to show detail)</sup></sub>

...and so on.

We continue, then, to write another Python program (using PIL, of course). We make the following assumptions: a pixel is considered dark when the sum of its R, G, and B values is less than 350; a pixel is considered light when the sum of its R, G, and B values is greater than 500; and the binary is read from left to right and top to bottom.

The resulting binary string is: `01100110011011000110000101100111011110110110010000110000011011100111010001011111011101010101111101101010011101010011010101110100010111110011000100110000001100000011000000110000001100000011000001110110001100110011001100110011010111110110001101110010011110010111000001110100001100000011111101111101`

Converting this to ASCII, we get: `flag{d0nt_u_ju5t_1000000v333_crypt0?}` and this is our flag!

Comment: Tbh, it's not hard to come up with the idea of solving until the penultimate steps (as many people aware or at least me, we have to "swap" then convert to binary). The last step however, need some assumption i.e. "considered dark if sum < 350" and "considered light if sum > 500". This kind of assumption should be generally avoided. I actually tried to find something with R or G or B to get the bit, e.g. by xor-ing them or else, because a good puzzle needs to have a deterministic step to solve. If you want solvers to get that assumption, it's better to leave a clue of 350 and 500 somewhere.

Comment: athin echoes my thoughts exactly. As someone who does a lot of CTFs, this challenge would certainly be complained about in an actual CTF as being way too guessy.

Comment: @athin -- Your problems with the threshold can easily be avoided. The actual thresholds I used when encoding these images was very different and the differences between a dark and a light pixel were ensured to be enough that decoding was possible.

Comment: @Quintec -- Your problems with the threshold can easily be avoided. The actual thresholds I used when encoding these images was very different and the differences between a dark and a light pixel were ensured to be enough that decoding was possible.

Comment: I also think this required way too many guesses, including the order of reading bits, the idea of converting them to ASCII, the guessing of what pixels are considered dark and what pixels are considered light and the structure of the text file (is it old_x old_y new_x new_y, or new_x new_y old_x old_y or something else?)

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate -- I will address your points in order. 1) Order of reading bits: going from left to right and then to the next row from top to bottom is the natural reading order for the English language and many other languages as well. Additionally, in a CTF, you are expected to be able to try multiple possible direction, methods, etc. to get to the flag, so this fits right in. 2) The structure of the text file is rather obvious. You can see the image has 37 cols and 8 rows, and the text file's numbering is structured as such also. Furthermore, if there are just two (cont'd.)

Comment: (cont'd.) possibilities for the text file (i.e., `OLD_X OLD_Y NEW_X NEW_Y` or `NEW_X NEW_Y OLD_X OLD_Y`), you can try both of them. Again, very common for a CTF problem. 3) Thresholding the values of pixels to dark and light: If you look at Carl Löndhal's comment on Quintec's answer, you'll see that doing that would work as well. I left quite a large amount of space between dark and light pixels to ensure that there would be a difference between them (and ensure that they were differentiable). 4) This is the most obvious of your concerns. Converting binary to ASCII is seen in (cont'd.)

Comment: (cont'd.) literally every CTF. It's the most common thing in the world. Many of my comments in response to yours relate to this being a very common format in CTFs, so perhaps this is not something you are well-versed in (which is fine, BTW). However, it still remains that the problem applies just fine to a CTF and the topic. It is also _very_ solvable for the reasons mentioned in the previous two comments.

Comment: I consider myself well-versed in CTFs, and I didn't like the problem, especially after seeing the correct solution. As you can easily see from looking at the other answers, all the people who tried to solve this simply haven't tried enough possibilities to obtain the flag. I do not think a good problem should require this much guesswork. I also feel like the 3 last comments you posted here are saying pretty much "This is a good problem, you're all wrong" (literal quote: "applies just fine to a CTF and the topic").

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate -- _There is no guesswork involved!_

Comment: I must agree with Voldemort on this one. I would say that it was not THAT guessy. I mean the mapping to ASCII was pretty obvious, at least if you played a few CTFs. Also the three coordinates being used suggested that some distance (1 or 2-norm was used) and based on the hints a map to binary should be mostly evident. But I cannot say this is my favorite type of problem (and you see similiar problems from time to time), I don’t find it very entertaining so I never attempted to solve it.

Comment: Can you provide the code you used to unscramble the image?  I am not sure that it works as you intended, since many of the NEW_X NEW_Y coordinates are repeated.  For example, the key contains lines 30 3 0 6 and 30 7 0 6.  I'm not sure which way your scramble goes, but the pixels at 30,3 and 30,7 are not the same, so I think you did your scramble in the other direction.  This would mean that many of the original pixels were lost when you did your scramble, and that your original image can not be fully recovered from the information provided.

Comment: If anything, I see no reason to make the picture after the scramble have so many colors. Making it not grayscale has no purpose other than making it guessy.

Answer (score 2):

**Partial**

From the hints, it's fairly evident the image is scrambled, and the key seems to list

> Two coordinates, presumably new and old coordinates.

Applying this scramble with the below script

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open('flag.png')
width, height = im.size

with open('key.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

key = {}
for line in lines:
    nums = list(map(int, line.split(' ')))
    key[(nums[0], nums[1])] = (nums[2], nums[3])

orig = np.array(im)

arr = np.zeros([height, width, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
for (x1, y1) in key:
    (x2, y2) = key[(x1, y1)]
    arr[y2][x2] = orig[y1][x1]

img = Image.fromarray(arr, 'RGB')
img.save('new.png')
```

gives

[image]

(compression has murdered the image, but you can run the script yourself)

And now I don't know where to go.

Comment: I think my code is wrong oops

Comment: You're on the write track... but I'm not sure what you did to `flag.png`. That's not at all what it should look like. Additionally, you're not interpreting Hint 1 correctly. Just assume that Hints 1 and 2 are hinting at the same thing.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath fixed my image... i think... still no idea though

Comment: That image is better, now, I think. None of the image's pixels should be black but it's tough to tell if they are or not.

Comment: Did you try mapping the columns to ASCII? The columns are $8$ high, so if the image is made binary (by thresholding $>127$) maybe that will give a flag of length $37$?

Comment: You'll end up getting half the bounty because I don't foresee anyone getting the correct answer between now and when it expires.

Comment: [My writeup](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/99067/58672) has been posted!

Comment: @CarlLöndahl -- If you see [my writeup](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/99067/58672), you'll see that you were spot-on!

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

> In order to unscramble the image, I interpreted the key.txt file as pairs of coordinates - the first (x,y) is telling me which pixel to set, and the second (x,y) is telling me which pixel to get from the flag to set it as. (I also tried this vice-versa). So, the unscrambled flag looks like this: [image: enter description here]  OR, inverted, looks like this: [image] (screenshots for ease of viewing) ...these obviously don't look like anything, and even taking the RGB and converting that to binary gives me nonsense. Threshholding values to find a black and white pattern like Carl mentioned in the comment on Quintec's answer didn't work either. I'm stumped but I do think that my interpretation of the key is correct.

Comment: You are also on the right path! Not sure why you would invert the image, but ok. I will tell you this: something of what you said in your answer is veeeeeery close to what you have to do to get the flag now. Keep thinking!

Comment: [My writeup](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/99067/58672) has been posted!

Answer (score 2):

Another idea

> Firstly, swap pixels on coordinates listed in key.txt file

```
from PIL import Image
picture = Image.open("./flag.png")

key = open('./key.txt', 'r')

# Read coordinates and swap those pixels
line = key.readline();
while line:
    coords = list(map(int, line.split(" ")))
    line = key.readline()
    pixelA = picture.getpixel( (coords[0] , coords[1]) )
    pixelB = picture.getpixel( (coords[2], coords[3]) )
    picture.putpixel( (coords[0] , coords[1]), pixelB )
    picture.putpixel( (coords[2], coords[3]), pixelA )

picture.save("decoded.png")
```

The picture I've obtained looks like that: [image]

> Next step is swapping binary data in this file using below line
>  "< decoded.png xxd -p -c1 | tac | xxd -p -r > swapped.png"
>  Then I've inspected hexdump of the file, but the flag wasn't there. I would appreciate a hint if it's possible. I was thinking about copying pixels instead swapping, but ended up with the same result.

Comment: Keep up the amazing work! This is on the right track and is still very close!

Comment: [My writeup](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/99067/58672) has been posted!