# To be decoded (BINARY)

Tags: cipher, visual

Look at this image using a pixel editor. Black is 0, white is 1 and
red is end of statement

[image]

Comment: Your image is tiny. Can you enlarge it?

Comment: @TobyMak I'm pretty sure it's supposed to be :)

Comment: I don't think requiring a pixel editor is a good idea. I'll see what I can do about blowing this up.

Comment: This reminds me of [one of my own puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98797/scrambler-puzzle-ctf-forensics-problem-by-me)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [this pixel editor](https://lospec.com/pixel-editor/app) to zoom in we find it looks like this:

> [image]

And also taking a grey as a '1' then the binary is

> 01001000
> 01100101
> 01101100
> 01101100
> 01101111

Which is ASCII for

> **'Hello'**

Comment: Good job everyone!